# How to fix squares instead of text(emojis) on webpages

Tags: text, encoding, utf-8, fonts, character-encoding

After I've reinstalled my system I'm seeing squares instead of some text (or emojis) in browsers.
Here's a sample view of outlook in brave browser:

[image]

I suppose it has something to do with locales/encoding, but I'm not sure how to fix this.

I've tried `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales` but it didn't seem to have helped.

This is the output of `locale` command:

```
LANG=en_US.utf8
LANGUAGE=en_US.utf8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.utf8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.utf8"
LC_TIME="en_US.utf8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.utf8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.utf8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.utf8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.utf8"
LC_NAME="en_US.utf8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.utf8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.utf8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.utf8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.utf8"
LC_ALL=en_US.utf8
```

And the fonts that are set in ubuntu gnome tweaks settings:
[image]

UPD:
As I noticed this only happens on some pages. I suppose it has to do with how a particular page renders text into an emoji? Still not sure how to fix this though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case someone has the same issue will post a solution I've found so far.
In essence I've narrowed it down to a problem with fonts since locale and encoding seems fine.

After installing `ttf-ancient-fonts` and `ttf-ancient-fonts-symbola` with `apt`:
[image]

So this is an improvement. Still I'm wondering what font I had previously that is missing now, since before the emojis were colored.